# .NET 8 MAUI (Android) SignalR connection initialization takes 1.5 minutes

Tags: android, http, .net-core, signalr, maui

I have trouble with initializing a SignalR connection (.NET 8 MAUI client, .NET 8 server) since a couple of days:

- .NET 8 MAUI Android SignalR application trying to connect to a .NET 8 SignalR Hub.
- .NET 8 GA is being used - before that .NET 8 RC versions.
- Issue is new-ish - it occurs for at least a week now. Unkown when it started exactly as it works with Emulator.
- It often takes around 1.5 to initialize the SignalR (HTTP/HTTPS) connection. Sometimes there is an error. Sometimes it works just fine.
- As far as I can tell it is independent of HTTP / HTTPS usage.

**Client information**

- .NET 8 MAUI iOS and Android app, issue appearing on Android. I did not test in detail on iOS as reproducibility is limited even on Android.
- Works just fine in Android Emulator (Debug or Release builds).
- It is troublesome on physical devices (Debug or Release on Dev smartphone, Release via Android Store).
- Installed dotnet Workloads

  ```
  ios                        17.0.8478/8.0.100      VS 17.8.34309.116
  android                    34.0.43/8.0.100        VS 17.8.34309.116
  ```

**Server information**

- Service running in docker, .NET 8 GA
- Server is using Lets Encrypt certificates for the domains
- Docker container using the newest .NET 8 image template

**Code client (MAUI App)**

```cs
Hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(_ApiHubConnectionString)
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging => {
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
    })
    .Build();


// ...

Log.Debug("SignalR Hub starting, ConnectionString = {HubConnectionString}", _ApiHubConnectionString);
await Hub.StartAsync();
Log.Debug("SignalR Hub started, ConnectionString = {HubConnectionString}", _ApiHubConnectionString);
```

**Example Connection String**

- http://service.mydomain.net/myhub
- https://service.mydomain.net/myhub

**Code Server**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
});

// ...

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.MapHub<MyHub>($"/{nameof(MyHub)}");
```

**Logs nOK**

```
17:45:39.875  SignalR Hub starting, ConnectionString = URL
17:46:50.819  New connection -Qd4psbQgCumVVw3RED-uA created.
17:46:50.820  Sending negotiation response.
17:47:06.452  Removing connection bkSV_uGwzmEVsaa_82zXRA from the list of connections. // Don't know if this is related
17:47:58.771  New connection ZgJSXQLT0oNspEMjwyTkUg created.
17:47:58.771  Sending negotiation response.
              Note: all of the following is for connection ZgJSXQLT0oNspEMjwyTkUg
17:47:58.822  Establishing new connection.
17:47:58.823  OnConnectedAsync started.
17:47:59.018  Found protocol implementation for requested protocol: json.
17:47:59.018  Completed connection handshake. Using HubProtocol 'json'.
```

**Logs nOK, Connection error on client, exception thrown**

```
17:56:19.618  SignalR Hub starting, ConnectionString = URL
17:57:25.479  New connection t7UpffSa6MhxQXmnzY7bqA created.
17:57:25.479  Sending negotiation response.
17:57:41.449  Removing connection Wp41QfpkV7uGtt5xMNnmjw from the list of connections.
17:57:46.076  DisconnectHubAsync, State = Connecting
17:57:46.110  SignalR Hub error trying to connect to Hub (EXCEPTION)

Exception:
System.AggregateException: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports. (WebSockets failed: A task was canceled.) (ServerSentEvents failed: The operation was canceled.) (LongPolling failed: The operation was canceled.)
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.TransportFailedException: WebSockets failed: A task was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.<WaitWithCancellationAsync>d__1[[System.Net.Http.HttpConnection, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, HttpMessageInvoker invoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, HttpMessageInvoker invoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.DefaultWebSocketFactory(WebSocketConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.StartAsync(Uri url, TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartTransport(Uri connectUrl, HttpTransportType transportType, TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean useStatefulReconnect)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MYNAMESPACE.Services.ApiService.ConnectHubIfRequired()
 ---> (Inner Exception #1) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.TransportFailedException: ServerSentEvents failed: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, URL javaUrl, HttpURLConnection httpConnection, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestRedirectionState redirectState)
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.AccessTokenHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---

 ---> (Inner Exception #2) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.TransportFailedException: LongPolling failed: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, URL javaUrl, HttpURLConnection httpConnection, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestRedirectionState redirectState)
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.AccessTokenHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---
```

I tried

- Android emulator or physical devices, using Debug or Release builds.
- Multiple physical devices
- HTTP or HTTPS on the server / client.
- Check DNS lookup, seems fine.
- Tried to get propber logs -> increasing / setting log levels.
- Tried to simplify the .NET Blazor backend (used services / configuration).
- Played around with SignalR timeouts on client side.
- Using different domains.
- Cleaning bin/obj folders
- Restarting Visual Studio, restarting computer
- Reinstalled / removed app on devices most of the time during testing

Comment: Did you manage to find the cause because I am having the same issue.

Comment: Hey @AlpUygur, I actually found a solution. In my case the IPv6 DNS configuration was faulty. A ping to the ipv6 ip did not work from all kind of clients but from some of them.